# Dato de Firebase a un TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, textview

Quiero tomar el dato "nickname" de la base de datos de Firebase y reemplazarlo por un textView en Android Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**texto en negrita**

Comment: Eso seria un json?

Comment: Te sugerimos agregar siempre lo que has tratado. revisa [ask], edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tu app esta en java, te dejo como traer ese texto

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Users");

        ref.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String nickname = dataSnapshot.child("nickname").getValue(String.class);
            tu_textView.setText(nickname);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Falló la operación: " + databaseError.getCode());
          }
        });
```

Comment: Lo mejor sería pedir aclaraciones al usuario  y posteriormente contestar.

Comment: entendido @Jorgesys, disculpas